# Submit Array with Form to Node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, forms

I'm trying to create an array in Javascript based off of HTML input elements, then submit that array to my Node backend. So far I've only managed to console.log its value as [Object object] or undefined on server. Here is where I create the array:

```
var ingArray = [];
let ing_form = document.getElementsByClassName('add-ingredient-form');
for(var i=0; i< ing_form.length; i++) {
  let ing_form_input = document.querySelectorAll('.add-ingredient-form:nth-of-type('+(i+1)+') > .ing-option');

  ing_form_input.forEach(function(ing_input) {
    let name = ing_input.name.slice(0,19) + i + ing_input.name.slice(19);
    ing_input.setAttribute('name', name)
  })

  let newIng = {
      quantity: ing_form_input[0].value,
      measurement: ing_form_input[1].value,
      name: ing_form_input[2].value
  }

  ingArray.push(newIng);
}
```

When console.logged this array looks right. Here is where I submit the array:

```
var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'ingredientArray');
hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', ingArray);
form.appendChild(hiddenInput);


form.submit();
```

EDIT: I am trying to add this array to a MongoDB schema.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Try logging with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @destoryer tried that with no avail

Comment: What do you get out of it when you pass in the value that logged as `[Object object]`?

Comment: @destoryer That's what's logged when I log req.body.ingredientArray. Is that what you mean?